# Intersection of two projective submanifolds in $P^n$ treatment in Shafarevich book

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I would like to understand if the following statement is actually proven in Shafarevich's book "Basic algebraic geometry" (or just learn its proof in the spirit of Shafarevich's book).

**Statement**. Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field and let $X, Y$ be irreducible projective subvarieties in $\mathbb P_K^n$. Suppose that $\dim X+\dim Y\ge n$. Then $X\cap Y$ is non-empty.

It is proven in section 1.6, Theorem 5, that provided a form $F$ is non-vanishing on $X$, all irreducible components of $X\cap F=0$ have dimension $\dim X-1$. So if $Y$ were a complete intersection the statement $X\cap Y\ne \emptyset$ would immediately follow from this theorem. At the same time $Y$ need not be a complete intersection…. A few lines after Theorem 6 in the same section Shafarevich mentions that the **statement** holds. But I can not find the proof in the book. So, is the proof really missing or did I just miss something simple?

Comment: In my copy of the book 'Basic Algebraic Geometry I: Varieties in Projective Space' by Shafarevich, Theorem 6 is basically what your statement is - this is on page 76. This is the 'Second, Revised and Expanded Edition'. I can type it out for you, if you'd like.

Comment: Dear Ruadhai, thank you for telling this, I would be greatfull if you could state the version of the theorem in this edition 

Comment: the non emptiness statement does not follow from a bound on the dimension of the components, since any bound holds when there are no non empty components.  Rather the result follows from the diagonal trick as explained by Sandor, plus the further trick of considering the affine cones of the two intersecting varieties.  Since the corresponding homogeneous affine varieties must have the origin in common, the non emptiness hypothesis holds for the affine cones, and hence the dimension conclusion holds, and also the non emptiness holds, in the projective space setting.

Comment: The idea of taking affine cones is really nice...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't know how Shafarevich proves it or intended to prove it, but here is a way to do it.

**Claim:** Let $X,Y\subseteq \mathbb A^n$ irreducible of dimension $a,b$. Then every (non-empty!) irreducible component of $X\cap Y$ has dimension at least $a+b-n$.

**Sketch of Proof:** Step 1: using the Krull principle ideal theorem prove this in the case $Y$ is a hypersurface and then iterating it implies it if $Y$ is a complete intersection.

Step 2: use the diagonal trick: let $\Delta\subset \mathbb A^n\times \mathbb A^n$ be the diagonal and $$\delta:\mathbb A^n\to \Delta$$ the map given by $x\mapsto (x,x)$, then $\delta$ induces an isomorphism between $X\cap Y$ and $(X\times Y)\cap \Delta$. Since $\Delta\subset \mathbb A^n\times \mathbb A^n$ is a complete intersection, you can use your argument for this intersection (and you can check that the dimensions work out, too).

Now to prove the projective case, notice that if you take the cones over the projective subvarieties, then they necessarily intersect and hence the above claim can be applied to their intersection.
The claim in this case implies that (each irreducible component of) the intersection of the affine cones has to have at least dimension one, which implies that then there is a point other than the origin in it, which gives you an actual point on the intersection of the projective varieties.

Comment: This is how Shafarevich proves in my version of his book.

Comment: Could you explain why the diagonal $\Delta \subset \mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{P}^n$ is a complete intersection? Wouldn't you need ${n+1 \choose 2}$ equations in $\mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{P}^n$ given by the vanishing $x_iy_j-x_jy_i$ where the coordinates of $\mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{P}^n$ are $([x_0, \dots, x_n],[y_0, \dots, y_n])$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are absolutely right, I did this in a very sloppy way. The diagonal in projective space is a *local* complete intersection, which is usually good enough for whatever one might use complete intersections. I fixed the answer...